# Angular 2: How to pass route parameters to subroute?

Tags: typescript, routes, angular

Using Angular 2 rc.1 and TypeScript.  I'm having a lot of trouble passing routing parameters to my component when the component is loaded in a subroute. I use the `@angular/router-deprecated` package.

In my **root component**, I configured the routes as such:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/top', name:'Top', component: EndPointComponent},
  {path:'/sub/...', name:'Sub', component: MiddleManComponent}
])
```

Here is the **endpoint component** where I attempt to read the parameters

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
@Component({
    template: 'Route Params: {{routeParams.params | json}}'
})
export class EndPointComponent{
    constructor(private routeParams:RouteParams){}
}
```

Here is the **middleman component** with the subroute to EndPointComponent

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {EndPointComponent} from "./endpoint.component";

@Component({
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/end', name: 'End', component: EndPointComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
export class MiddleManComponent {}
```

The parameters can be successfully read from the `routeParams` object of `EndPointComponent` when the component is loaded from the top-level route (eg: the route named 'Top' in the root component).  However, the parameters are always empty when I navigate to `EndPointComponent` by going throug `MiddleManComponent` (eg: via the route named 'Sub' in the root component).

Do children routers scrub the parameters from parents before resolving the routes? That doesn't make much sense so I bet I'm missing something. My question is simply: how do I pass route parameters to a subroute?

PS: I tried to build a plunker to [demo this setup](http://plnkr.co/edit/zlEPWs10ileV0XrlggyA) but I gave up when I couldn't figure out why the application doesn't load.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child routes actually get their own instance of RouteParams, distinct from the parent route's.  This is done to avoid naming collisions and facilitate encapsulation of the routed component.

One way you can share a parent route's parameters with a component loaded by a child route is through a service.

```
@Injectable()
export class RouteParamService {
  constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams) {}

  get params() {
    return this.routeParams.params;
  }
}

@Component({
    template: 'Route Params: {{routeParams.params | json}}'
})
export class EndPointComponent{
    constructor(private routeParams:RouteParamService){}
}

@Component({
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  providers: [RouteParamService]
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/end', name: 'End', component: EndPointComponent, useAsDefault: true}
])
class MiddleManComponent() { }
```

The RouteParamService will be instantiated at the same route level as the MiddleManComponent and so will get the same instance of RouteParams.  When your service gets injected into your child route component, you'll be able to access the parent route params.

If you need 2 instances of EndPointComponent to load at different route tree levels, you'll need another tier of parent route, I think; i.e. a routed component that encapsulates both MiddleManComponent and EndPointComponent, between RootComponent.

RootComponent is not routed, so you won't be able to instantiate  RouteParams for the RouteParamService from it.  RouteParams is provided by the `<router-outlet>` component.

Comment: Thank you. This is a really interesting solution.  It seems a bit hacky though doesn't it? As far as you know, Angular 2 has no built-in solution to this? I would think my use case is really common unless my components architecture is badly conceived. PS: the built-in solution if one exists might be in `@angular/router` rather than the older `@angular/router-deprecated`

Comment: It does start to feel hacky when you try to have the same component instantiated at different route levels.  If you need the top-level route's parameters, then you basically need a component dedicated just to instantiating your service and pushing your other components down one level.  That's one reason why I think it's a design mistake that top level components don't have access to RouteParams.  That said, though, using services to share data between components is a common design pattern for Angular applications.

Answer (score 3):

Using `@angular/router@3.4.7`, you can access the parent `ActivatedRoute` with

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  parentRouteId: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.params
      .subscribe((params: Params) => this.parentRouteId = params['id']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.6" package, i was able to get the parent route argument by doing the following:

```
export class ChildComponent {

    private sub: any;

    private parentRouteId: number;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.sub = this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.subscribe(params => {
            this.parentRouteId = +params["id"];
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

In this example the route has the following format: `/parent/:id/child/:childid`

```
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '/parent/:id',
        component: ParentComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '/child/:childid', component: ChildComponent }]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `ActivatedRote` and take a snapshot, even easier:

`constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {};
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log('one of my parents route param:',            this.route.snapshot.parent.params['PARAM-NAME']);
  }`

Comment: Thanks. The answer I selected worked for me at the time. Angular has changed quite a bit since then and I've actually done exactly what you suggest since moving to `rc 4` or `rc 5`