# How best to include tenant in Angular 2 Routing

Tags: angular2-routing

I'm pretty new to Angular 2 and a little confused as to whether I'm approaching this problem in the right way. I'm writing a multi-tenant app and I would like all the url's to start with the tenant id. An example would be: `https://example.org/tenant-1/product/list` or `https://example.org/tenant-2/product/list`. This seems like quite a simple and well solved problem, but I'm having trouble finding a recommended way of achieving this.

So far I have created a routing service:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoutingService {
    public ClientId: string = null;

    constructor() {}

    getRoute(path: string): string {
        if (!this.ClientId) {
            // For deep-linking
            this.ClientId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
        }

        return '/' + this.ClientId + path;
    }
}
```

The user is presented a list of tenants and selects one. This sets the `ClientId` on the `RoutingService`.

Within each component, I'm importing this `RoutingService` in the constructor and the HTML uses it to create the route:

```
[routerLink]="[routingService.getRoute('/product/list')]
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?  I have a similar use case.

Comment: I found this answer very helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438786/how-to-achieve-multi-tenant-routing-in-angular?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I am in a similar situation as yourself and it seems like pulling it from a service is the way to do it currently because of component encapsulation/isolation:

[Angular 2: How to pass route parameters to subroute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37403545/angular-2-how-to-pass-route-parameters-to-subroute/37403745#37403745)

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters

Instead of creating a RouteService or RouteParamService, I am baking it into my AuthService since tenant is part of authentication.  Other than tenant the route parameters work fine in isolation in my case.