# How to achieve multi tenant routing in angular?

Tags: angular, angular5

I am looking for implementing **multi tenant routing mechanism** where the `URL` should look like:

```
myapp.com/tenant-1/dashboard, 
myapp.com/tenant-2/dashboard.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to declare your routing like this, where /:tenant_id will be dynamically generated.

```
{ 
    path: 'tenant/:tenant_id', 
    children: [
       { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
       { path: 'SomeOther', component: SomeOtherComponent }
    ]
}
```

You'll read the :tenant_id with the below code:

```
this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
       let tenant_id = params['tenant_id'];
       console.log(tenant_id);
});
```

Comment: How can we have different DNS for each tenant in this?

Comment: as angular is a client side app, you can not have it implemented as subdomains.

Answer (score 3):

Then your routing declaration should look like this :

```
{ path: ':tenant', children: [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent }
]}
```